# Speak with English?

Tags: prepositions

It's just come to my mind why people say *speak in English* rather than *speak with English*. Why is it not appropriate to use *with* instead of *in* here? You *speak with English accent*, but why not *speak with English?*

Comment: The grammar isn't right. Or it doesn't sound like a natural English speaker would say it.  We speak in English or in French, or we speak with an English accent .

Comment: You just don't do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just idiomatic*. As Oxford Dictionaries says under the definition for [in](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in):

> indicating the language or medium used: *say it in Polish* | *put it in writing.*

On the other hand, the definition for [with](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/with) says:

> indicating the manner or attitude of the person doing something: *with great reluctance*.

<sub>*At least that's the best explanation there is without doing a lot of research. And when you finally find an explanation, it's likely to be very complex, and probably not worth the effort.</sub>